# Data Vectorization

Tags: machine-learning, vectorization

Met a tricky issue when trying to vectorize my feature. I have a feature like this:

- most of it is numeric, like 0, 1, 33.3, 100, etc.
- some of is empty, which represents not provided.
- some of it is "auto", which means it adapts the context.

Now my question is, how to encode this feature into vectors effectively? One thing I can do is just to treat all numerical value as categorical too, but that will result in an explosion in the feature space, also not good for representing similar data points. What should I do?

Thanks!

--- THE ALGORITHM/MODEL I'M USING ---

It's LSTM (Long Short Term Memory) neural network. Currently I'm going with the following approach say I have 2 data points:

         `col1
entry1:  1.0
entry2:  auto`

It'll be encoded into:

         `col1-a  col1-b
entry1:   1.0       0
entry2:  dummy      1`

So col1-b will represent whether it's auto or not. The dummy number will be the median of all the numeric data.  Will this work?

Also, I for each numeric value they have a unit associated, so there's another column which has value like 'px', 'pt', in this case, does the numeric value still has meaning if I extracted the unit into another column? They has actual meaning when associated (numeric + unit), but can the NN notice that if they are on different dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what type of algorithm you you will be using. If you want to use something like association rule classification then you will have to treat all of your variables as categorical data. If you want to use logistic regression, then that isn't needed. You'd have to provide more details to get a better answer.

**edit**
I made some edits after reading your edit.

It sounds like what you have is at least reasonable. I've read books where people use the mean/median/mode to fill in missing values for numeric data. As for which specific one works the best for you I don't know. Can you try training your classifier with each version?

As for your issue with the "auto" column, it sounds like you want to do something similar to running a [regression with categorical data](http://www.r-bloggers.com/regression-on-categorical-variables/). I don't have much experience with neural networks, but I know that if you were to use something like logistic regression then this is the approach you would want to use. Hopefully this gives you an idea of what you have to research.

As far as treating all of your numerical data as categorical data, you can do that as well, but you have to normalize it first. You can do something like [min-max normalization](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/03preprocessing-140913211250-phpapp02/95/data-mining-concepts-and-techniques-3rd-ed-chapter-3-preprocessing-51-638.jpg?cb=1410642919) and then just take the interger part of the number. Now your data will be the same as categorical data.

Comment: Thank you very much, Taylor! I edited the problem and asked about the vectorization of something like '11px', '12pt' too. Does this make more sense now?

Comment: Thank you very much Taylor!